# Get date from table and set it to a datepicker jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datetimepicker

I have a problem to get a date value from a table row and post it by jQuery to a datepicker with a HTML input field with type date. I Am using MVC to to fill the table with data. Here is my code. Invoice.DueDate is of type datetime and gets read as an empty string for now. Any suggestions?

```cs
<tbody>
    @foreach (var invoice in Model.InvoiceList)
    {
        <tr>
            <td id="InvoiceN" class="change align-center">
                <a href="#backdropreport" class="btn-sm btn-primary  UpdateInvoice"  
                    data-invoiceDueDate="@(invoice.DueDate)">Ändra</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>

 <div class="form-group">
     <label for="date">Förfallodatum</label>
     <input type="date" id="date" name="start"/>
 </div>

$(".UpdateInvoice").click(function () {
    var invoiceDueDate = $(this).attr("data-invoiceDueDate");
    $("#date").val(invoiceDueDate);
});
```

So the question is how to read proper date value from table and post the date to a datepicker.

Comment: So the database value is not sent properly to your datepicker? What is the actual value and format from the database (yyyy-mm-dd)?

Comment: How does this not work? by the sounds of it you havn't actually put in a datetime to the data-invoiceDueDate, try it and see if it works, when it doesn, please send us what MVC renders (view source + coppy/paste)

Comment: javascript doesn't recognize your server side dateTime ...need to format it to an iso string in same format you set datepicker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your using the HTML5 datapicker (note that this is only supported in Chrome) so you need to format the date as ISO format - i.e. `yyyy-MM-dd`

You could do this using

```
data-invoiceDueDate="@invoice.DueDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")"
```

or by using the `DisplayFormat` attribute and setting the `DisplayFormatString` property (and then using `data-invoiceDueDate="@Html.DisplayFor(m => invoice.DueDate)"`

Refer [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xoz92jd0/) for an example of using both an invalid format and the ISO date format

Side note: You are creating duplicate `id` attributes in your `foreach` loop by your use of `<td id="InvoiceN" ...` which is invalid html

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to fix the problem with getting the right format on the datetime object and posting it to a datepicker,

My solution was to use moment.js to get the right format.

```
 $(".UpdateInvoice").click(function () {
        var invoiceDueDate = $(this).attr("data-invoiceDueDate");
        var date = moment(invoiceDueDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
        $("#date").val(date);
    });
```

Comment: Isn't that what said in my answer

Comment: I tried your way but it was not allowed to call ToString("YYYY-MM-DD" ) in the view so i had to use another way. But thanks to you i found moment.js :) @StephenMuecke